# C Losing pointer to pointer reference

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, debugging, reference

Im able to find the most frequent letter, ***but when trying to print the elements in **words again, Im given \000 values.***

I tried to store head into another variable but seems like I still lose all reference.
I also tried to pass it as a constant but I still lose reference. `void findFrequentLetter(const char **words)` and also modified the call with const. How can I make this work?

I know the problem is in the first ***for(while())*** loop.

```
void findFrequentLetter(char const **words) {
   int array[255] = {0}; // initialize all elements to 0
   char str[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   int i, max;
   for (int d = 0; d < nb_words; ++d) {
      while (**words != '\0'){
         ++array[**words];
         ++(*words);
      }
      ++words;
   }
// Find the letter that was used the most
   max = array[0];
   int index = 0;
   for (i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
      if (array[str[i]] > max ) {
         max = array[str[i]];
         index = i;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the magic number 42?

Comment: How does the passed argument look?

Comment: Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Why doesn't the loop use `d`?

Comment: Your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is in serious need of explanation of this code.

Comment: Fyi, *"42 is simply the number of words Im iterating through (contained in **words)"* - that needs to be a caller-provided argument to the function, not some magic value hard-coded into the code here.

Comment: Does the bug disappear if you scan only 41 words? I second @VladfromMoscow's request for a minimal complete example.

Comment: I third that. Your post needs to be a proper [mcve]. Setup a `main` that stacks the words you purport to being sent to this, in the array structure you claim you're using, calls your function, and exhibits the issue you're having.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think youll be able to see it now

Comment: Potential bug; mismatched types for an allocation:`struct Stats *stats = malloc(sizeof(struct noeud));`. This will appear to work fine on systems where `sizeof (char *) + sizeof (struct noeud *) == sizeof (int) * 4`, but otherwise may over- or under-allocate memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
for (int d = 0; d < stats->mot_sans_doublons; ++d)
{
    while (**words != '\0')
    {
        ++array[**words];
        ++(*words); // <===== HERE
    }
    ++words;
}
```

Your code is given the base address to an array of pointers. Each of those pointers refers to a string. The line in question above advances the pointers in that array... *permanently*. The underlying array of pointers has each pointer within that array permanently walked to the end of their respective strings.

The *correct* way to walk those strings is by intermediate pointer. Do NOT modify the content of `words` in *any* way. For example:

```
for (int d = 0; d < stats->mot_sans_doublons; ++d)
{
    for (const char *s = words[d]; *s; ++s)
        ++array[(unsigned char)*s];
}
```

Whether the rest of your code 'works' I leave to you, but that is the reason why, after calling your frequency counter, your words array seems to have "lost its references".

Comment: Ok, Ill go study that. Thank you for the input.